# Mark tag as "interesting" or "ignored" from that tag's page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Right now, if I want to add a tag to my list of "interesting" or "ignored" tags, I have to go to the home page, type in the tag name, and click Add.

I think this would work better if, while I was on the page for the "foo" tag (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo), there were "Mark as interesting" and "Mark as ignored" buttons somewhere, such as on the right side, underneath the "42 questions tagged foo sorted by..." text.

Comment: similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/ability-to-add-tag-to-interesting-ignored-by-clicking-on-it

Answer (score 12):

On most pages, we now [enable a hover menu on every tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/tag-favorites-and-tag-subscriptions/):

[image: hover menu]

This supports adding *and* removing from the interesting/ignored tag list. Click the star to toggle between:

- favorite (gold star)
- no state (gray star)
- ignored (red X)

Credits to Alconja for suggesting this method!

Comment: Is this method still supported? I tried it (on that same question, eve) on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell but didn't see an option to add to interesting or ignored. Instead, there's a summary, subscribe & RSS options, and links to info, faq, and top users: http://cl.ly/8OMT

Comment: Good point, I updated my post.

Comment: Ahh, the star! Foiled by the star!!!

Comment: Super helpful!  Didn't realize i would cycle..i too was frustrated by not having an ignore quick-link.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For anyone interested, I built a greasemonkey script that (in a roundabout way) fulfils this feature request. Basically it allows adding/removing of interesting/ignored tags via a drop down menu available from any tag link anywhere on the site (including the tag's page).

[You can find the script over here...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/ability-to-add-tag-to-interesting-ignored-by-clicking-on-it/52884#52884)

---

[image: hover-tag-a-go-go]

Comment: Doesn't this pop up in way too many places to be useful?

Comment: @The Cat - Well, it's got a half second delay on it, so you don't really see it unless you make the deliberate choice to. And I think its useful being able to mark a tag as interesting from random places like on a question page.

Comment: we're looking at this as a model for implementation, but *only* on the `/tagged/` page -- thanks for contributing it!

Answer (score 2):

I'll add my request for this feature; I was in the middle of asking the same question when the search brought me here.

I would suggest that the ability to "Quick Add" or "Quick Ignore" a tag should be available on every question page as well as on the tag's page.

On a question page, I would suggest that the tags listed for that question include two buttons similar to the X button next to tags in your interesting or ignored list on the main page.

One button would have a + symbol rather than X with the hover background being blue or green rather than red. Alt text for the button would read "Mark Tag Interesting" or something similar. Clicking on that button would add the tag to the interesting list.

The other button would look like the canonical Do Not Enter sign: a red circle background with a white - symbol. No hover background change, but the alt text would read "Ignore This Tag" or something similar. Clicking on that button would add the tag to the ignored list.

Answer (score 1):

Using drag&drop on the tag <kbd>feature-request</kbd>  results in this:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request
```

(I just dragged the tag into the editor). This is more easily done by just clicking on the tag.

What if the interesting and ignored fields could just filter the tags name out of the URL or the tag would only drag&drop its tagname instead of the URL?

Maybe on the search field it could add [tagname].

Answer (score 0):

One of the first issues I had after my first quarter of an hour on StackOverflow was "Where is the *add* button on *tag page*?! am I blind?"

I think that is desirable usability feature.