# Tags page should hilight users interesting / ignored tags

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice if [tags page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) highlighted my interesting and ignored tags. Meta-SO gives some tags colours, but those are site-wide not personal.

Of course it would be even better if [you could manipulate them from there as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/ability-to-add-tag-to-interesting-ignored-by-clicking-on-it).

Comment: wouldn't it be better to highlight your interesting tags, and tags related to your interesting tags, but specifically *not* highlight your ignored tags?

Comment: Ignored in a different colour or style would seem most obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

A nice little enhancement. I would rate it as desirable, but low priority.